# How to align column of text in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I align a column of text to the right like the image below in react native? I have tried setting the `textAlign` to 'right' and setting `alignSelf` to 'flex-end', but it doesn't seem to be working.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30fX8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
            <View style={{alignItems:'flex-end'}}>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>TOTAL</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>100</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>200</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>300</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>400</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>500</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
```

The `alignItems` property in Flexbox only works when the items has the `flex` property.

Check the documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#align-items

Result:

[image]